# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException

Tags: c#, json, serialization

i'm trying to convert the json to C# objects by the statement

```
 var organizations = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Organization>>().Result;
```

i found so many questions like the same what i'm facing now but i didn't found the proper answer may i know the reason for this exception

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable `1[ConsoleApplication2.Organization]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

i'm trying to convert the json to C# objects by the statement
i found so many questions like the same what i'm facing now but i didn't found the proper answer may i know the reason for this exception
my Json is

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "message": "success",
    "organizations": [
        {
        "organization_id": "10234695",
        "name": "Zillium Inc",
        "contact_name": "John Smith",
        "email": "johnsmith@zilliuminc.com",
        "is_default_org": false,
        "plan_type": 0,
        "tax_group_enabled": true,
        "plan_name": "TRIAL",
        "plan_period": "",
        "language_code": "en",
        "fiscal_year_start_month": 0,
        "account_created_date": "2012-02-18",
        "account_created_date_formatted": "18 Feb 2012",
        "time_zone": "Asia/Calcutta",
        "is_org_active": true,
        "currency_id": "460000000000097",
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "currency_symbol": "$",
        "currency_format": "###,##0.00",
        "price_precision": 2
        },
        {
        "organization_id": "10407630",
        "name": "Winston Longbridge",
        "contact_name": "John Smith",
        "email": "johnsmith@zilliuminc.com",
        "is_default_org": false,
        "plan_type": 0,
        "tax_group_enabled": true,
        "plan_name": "TRIAL",
        "plan_period": "",
        "language_code": "en",
        "fiscal_year_start_month": 0,
        "account_created_date": "2012-07-11",
        "account_created_date_formatted": "11 Jul 2012",
        "time_zone": "Asia/Calcutta",
        "is_org_active": true,
        "currency_id": "541000000000099",
        "currency_code": "INR",
        "currency_symbol": "Rs.",
        "currency_format": "###,##0.00",
        "price_precision": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hari as you posted: `To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or chang e the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type  (e.g. not a primitive t ype like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) `

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to deserialize into an `IEnumerable<Organization>>` which is a list an therefor the serializer expects a json string defining a list/array like `[{a:b}, {a:n}]`

Your json data seems to be a normal json object and not an array.

This is causing the exception.